# Get User Account Status (Locked/Unlocked) from Active Directory on C-Sharp / C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I need to find a way to check if an Active Directory UserAccount has his account locked or not.

I've tried userAccountControl property in a Windows 2000 AD but that property does not change a byte when I force an account to get locked (by trying to log on to a workstation providing the wrong password for that specific user) And I can tell by using [ADExplorer.exe](http://live.sysinternals.com/adexplorer.exe) utility made by semi-god -> Mr. Russinovich

I've seen that in the 3.5 Framework they use the method .InvokeGet("userLockedOut"); but I'm trying to do this in a Enterprise Application that was written in .Net Framework 1.1 and there's no chance of using newer ones (just if you thought of suggesting so).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link with all the info on Active Directory stuff...

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply.... this article found at codeproject which every other post in the Net refers to is not for .Net Framework 1.1 is for 2.0 and above...

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx#45

Answer (score 3):

Found this, it is a little more than I have done in the past (can't find exact snippets) though the key is doing a directory search and limiting based on the lockouttime for your user(s) that are returned. Additionally for a particular user, you can limit your search further using additional properties. The codeproject link above has that particular logic (for search limiting) I believe.

```
class Lockout : IDisposable
{
  DirectoryContext context;
  DirectoryEntry root;
  DomainPolicy policy;

  public Lockout(string domainName)
  {
    this.context = new DirectoryContext(
      DirectoryContextType.Domain,
      domainName
      );

    //get our current domain policy
    Domain domain = Domain.GetDomain(this.context);

    this.root = domain.GetDirectoryEntry();
    this.policy = new DomainPolicy(this.root);      
  }

  public void FindLockedAccounts()
  {
    //default for when accounts stay locked indefinitely
    string qry = "(lockoutTime>=1)";

    TimeSpan duration = this.policy.LockoutDuration;

    if (duration != TimeSpan.MaxValue)
    {
      DateTime lockoutThreshold =
        DateTime.Now.Subtract(duration);

      qry = String.Format(
        "(lockoutTime>={0})",
        lockoutThreshold.ToFileTime()
        );
    }

    DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(
      this.root,
      qry
      );

    using (SearchResultCollection src = ds.FindAll())
    {
      foreach (SearchResult sr in src)
      {
        long ticks =
          (long)sr.Properties["lockoutTime"][0];

        Console.WriteLine(
          "{0} locked out at {1}",
          sr.Properties["name"][0],
          DateTime.FromFileTime(ticks)
          );
      }
    }
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    if (this.root != null)
    {
      this.root.Dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

Code was pulled from this post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/5e0fadc2-f27b-48f6-a6ac-644e12256c67/

Comment: Thank you Joshua, but unfortunately your solution which I had already seen surfing the web implements classes that are from .Net 2.0 and above
such as: 
HostSecurityManager.DomainPolicy Property
Note: This property is new in the .NET Framework version 2.0.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, didn't see the 1.1 in my excitement to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

After seeing the .NET 1.1, check this thread out: http://forums.asp.net/t/434077.aspx, using the lockouttime in the filter should still do the trick.

Specifically in the thread (after the larger code post which provides alot of the syntax):

```
(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(lockoutTime>=1));
```

One other thing, it turns out that if you are using .NET v.1.1, then S.DS converts the Integer8 to the long integer correctly for you (does not work with 1.0) - which means you can do away with reflection code (in the post):

```
//use the filter from above

SearchResultCollection src = ds.FindAll();  

foreach(SearchResult sr in src)

{

     DateTime lockoutTime = DateTime.FromFileTime((long)sr.Properties["lockoutTime][0]);

     Response.Output.Write("Locked Out on: {0}", lockoutTime.ToString());

}
```